# error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm trying to convert a project from VS2008 to VS2013 and one (of the many) problem's I have encountered is this:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(4953): error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found
```

I've searched the net for a solution, I have already include process.h in my StdAfx.h, (not sure if it matters, but I placed it below the #include  and #include  or else I receive a "Windows.h" already included error).

I am using MFC as shared dll, I am compiling with /MDd and checked that -D_MT flag is on.
(I am also not doing #undef _MT in my code).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In VS2013 you could use std::thread instead

Comment: The solution is not small, I really prefer not to change all the threads in the existing code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I had a different "process.h" file in one of the additional include directories, after adding "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" first in the additional include directories the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
#include <crtdefs.h>
#include <process.h>
```

crtdefs.h will define/undefine _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP which _beginthreadex is wrapped in within process.h.

Answer (score -1):

You have to include process.h to get access to this function.

Inside of an MFC application you should use AfxBeginThread.

Comment: Process.h is already included, thought I wrote it in the description of the problem but I found out that what I wrote in angle brackets is not shown, I updated the question.

Comment: Seems that _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP must be defined