# Visual Studio error when ITK and VTK is used

Tags: visual-studio, vtk, itk

I am doing a project in `visual studio 2015`When i included ITK and compiled everything ,some errors are occurring

```
    Error   C3861   '_beginthreadex': identifier not found

    Error   C2039   '_time64': is not a member of '`global namespace''  
    Error   C3861   '_time64': identifier not found     
    Error   C3861   '_mktime64': identifier not found   
    Error   C3861   '_mktime64': identifier not found   
    Error   C3861   '_gmtime64_s': identifier not found 
    Error   C3861   '_localtime64_s': identifier not found  
    Error   C3861   '_mktime64': identifier not found   
    Error   C3861   '_localtime64_s': identifier not found  
    Error   C3861   '_gmtime64_s': identifier not found 
    Error   C2039   '_time64': is not a member of '`global namespace''
    Error   C3861   '_time64': identifier not found 
    Error   C3646   'm_nLastAnimTime': unknown override specifier   
    Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
    support default-int 
    Error   C3646   'm_ActiveTime': unknown override specifier  
    Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
     support default-int    
    Error   C3646   'm_clkLastTime': unknown override specifier
```

But i tried including `Visual studio/VC/Include` and `Visual Studio/VC/bin` to the `Additional Include Directories`,still it is showing the same errors.
I also tried changing the `Use of MFC`   and  `c++ ->code generation ->Runtime Library in` `configuration properties` as well.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230258/error-c3861-beginthreadex-identifier-not-found) link also,but my problem is not solved.

So i thought may be because of vs2015 instalation problems and tried to build a new project using VTK and ITK  in `Visualstudio 2017`,In there also the same errors are occurring.I have been stuck for weeks ,Can anyone give a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [this procedure](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Configuring_and_Building/VisualStudio) to build ITK and VTK? Are you following [this guide](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/HelloInsight) to build your own application? Using CMake is the only supported way of using ITK and/or VTK.

If you cannot use CMake, a workaround is to build a hello world example using CMake and then copy include paths and list of libraries to your main Visual Studio application.